# What are the consequences of having zero Marksmanship?

Tags: jagged-alliance-2

Marksmanship (MRK) is a skill (like MEC, EXP, MED), so it can be dropped to zero.

I don't have the guts (and Vanilla 1.12-I bought it from GOG Games, but I don't know how to maintain two installations while not breaking the registry) to test it out, so I am instead asking it here. What happens next? MRK affects every gunshot, so if I drop her/his MRK to 0, can s/he ever shoot? What happens if s/he has to shoot? Does the crosshair ever appear? Also, can I drop MRK to 0 also in vanilla?

I expect answer for both vanilla (1.12) and 1.13 stable.

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR you cannot in vanilla, but if you *do* with cheating, then you can shoot, but never hit.

Source: [A Korean wiki called Namuwiki](https://namu.wiki/w/%EC%9E%AC%EA%B8%B0%EB%93%9C%20%EC%96%BC%EB%9D%BC%EC%9D%B4%EC%96%B8%EC%8A%A4%202/%EB%8A%A5%EB%A0%A5%EC%B9%98#s-3.2)